# How to postpone processing in ng-template until it's created?

Tags: angular

I have a modal component that I build which is pretty simple and looks similar to this:

```
<ng-template #content>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

I then dynamically create the `content` template using `@angular/cdk/overlay` when the modal is shown.

This system has worked great for me until just recently when I had a scenario where i needed a modal tied to each item in a long list. It also so happens that within each modal I am loading a largish amount of items e.g.

```
<my-modal>
  <div *ngFor="let item of lotsOfItems$ | async></div>
</my-modal>
```

I had assumed that since `<my-modal>` content was in a template that isn't being created until it's shown that `lotsOfItems$` wouldn't be subscribed to except when a modal was shown. If I add a `tap(console.log)` to that observable though I see that it is being subscribed to for each modal tied to each item in the list which is causing a really choppy DOM experience.

I poked around the documentation a bit and searched online, but I can't seem to find anything about how to defined and `<ng-template>` but not have any of the operations inside of it process until it's created.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should wrap `<div *ngFor="let item of lotsOfItems$ | async></div>` in `ng-template`

Comment: @yurzui it gets wrapped in an `ng-template` inside the modal component via `ng-content`. Is this not the same outcome?

Comment: Nope, Angular looks at the template where it's declared. And if it is not wrapped in `ng-template` then Angular renders it https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23756#issuecomment-387569480

Comment: @yurzui gotcha, I'll give that a try thanks. also I follow you on twitter, fun to run into you here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @yurzui's comment I decided to do this workaround to avoid the need to rewrite all current instances of `<my-modal>` component.

```
<my-modal #modal>
  <ng-container *ngIf="modal.visible">
    <div *ngFor="let item of lotsOfItems$ | async></div>
  </ng-container>
</my-modal>
```

Adding the `*ngIf` around my content wrapped it in an `ng-template` and i just bound that to the `visible` property i had on my `MyModalComponent` class.